# Find the good usepackage for a certain command

Tags: packages

I'm a beginner in LateX, and I was stuck on a question. How could I find easily the `\usepackage` for a command (e.g. `\href`)?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440588/latex-how-to-find-packages-that-a-command-belongs-to.

Comment: Why would you look for a command?  Wouldn’t you rather look for a package which offers certain functionality and then browse the list of available commands?  It often happens that there are several packages offering eponymous commands.

Comment: @HenriMenke Because many times we encounter a command in the context of code we get from somewhere else (like on TeX.se) and we want to know how it works and where it's from.  Given that commands can be TeX primitives, or defined in the kernel, or defined in some package (which could have been  loaded by another package) there are plenty of ways in which 'looking for functionality' is simply not relevant.